# Sharepoint 2010 ADFS 2.0 people picker

Tags: claims-based-auth

I've got a Sharepoint 2010 Server and on the same virtual machine ADFS 2.0. (It's a testing environment)

The Problem is, that sharepoint people picker doesnt show the claims when searching. These things on the left side, you know.

I also configured a role claim which is missing too. If i enter a email adress without opening the picker i can select the claim, and the login with the selected user works.

This are the configured ClaimMappings:

```
ClaimTypes                   : {
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress,  
http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role }
HasClaimTypeInformation      : True
ClaimTypeInformation         : {EmailAddress, Role}
```

And this is my ADFS Claim Rule

```
E-Mail-Addresses -> E-Mail Address
Token-Groups - Unqualified Names -> Role
```

I used several step by step guides. But none did help. Acording to them all you have to do is to configure the role mapping like described [here](http://lindstrom.nullsession.com/?p=236.)

Any Ideas what went wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually a hotfix did help. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2536591/en-us.

This is a sharepoint bug and the hotfix does fix it. Search for "people picker" on the kb-page and you will find following text: "After you apply the hotfix package that is described in KB article 2516472, the Trusted Identity claim provider does not appear when you open SharePoint People Picker in SharePoint Foundation 2010."

Comment: Answering your own question is fine, but please give us more details such as "why" this hotfix solved the problem. Please edit your post with additional details. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.

Comment: because this is a sharepoint bug and the hotfix does fix it. Search for "people picker" on the kb-page and you will find following text: "After you apply the hotfix package that is described in KB article 2516472, the Trusted Identity claim provider does not appear when you open SharePoint People Picker in SharePoint Foundation 2010."

Comment: Great, thanks for the clarification. I've moved that into the text of the answer to make it more visible.